# Comma before "by"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should a comma come before "by" when using passive voice?
Like in this sentence:

> Fractures are best treated by plates.

Comment: It would normally be "Fractures are best treated *with* plates".

Answer (score 2):

No, as you are not writing a list or needing to pause the reader for a better understanding of that partial sentence.  Hope this is helpful.